# Google Map API search request none English place ( SWIFT)

Tags: json, swift, xcode, google-maps, swift4

When I try to get the shop's coordinates on the browser I get the json results with no error using this link :

`"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=24.712587,46.673184&radius=5000&name=ستاربكس&key=#####"`

but when I do HTTP request via Alamofire in Xcode

```
let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=24.712587,46.673184&radius=5000&name=ستاربكس&key=####"

    let  requestURL =
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON
        { response in
            print(response.result.debugDescription)
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response)
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
    }
    }
```

I get nil for all prints !! Why is it doing this ? However, when I request a search for English names via Alamofire it works!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is something in Apple's framework tripped on the mix of Latin and Arabic characters. You can workaround it by separating the two components:

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=24.712587,46.673184&radius=5000&key=xxx")!
urlComponents.queryItems?.append(URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: "ستاربكس"))

let requestURL =
    Alamofire.request(urlComponents).responseJSON { response in
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just figured it out. I had to encode the name `encodeURI`